# Recover Android Maps API key

Tags: android, android-maps

Is recently created two API keys for the Android Maps API (one for debug and one for my key). But I didn't note down the keys. Is there any way to recover those keys form the google site or do I need to create new keys?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just supposed to generate a new one in this case.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I suppose the key is some sort of hashing function on the signing key hash.

Comment: I recently had the same problem, when you generate a new one you actually generate the same original key.